# display ServiceMark on android

Tags: android

I want to display the ServiceMark (SM) symbol in my application. I use its unicode value "\u2120" in my textview to do this, but it appears as a box on the emulator.
Is there any other solution to get this working?
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use superscript:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("Foobar<sup>SM</sup>"));
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but the text inside the <sup> tag appears as a normal text instead of being superscripted. Am i missing something?

Comment: @user678229, post your code. Have you set a different typeface or changed other settings of the TextView?

Comment: this is what i have in my layout file                         <TextView android:id="@+id/title" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="53dp" android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:textStyle="bold"
      android:textColor="@color/black" android:scrollHorizontally="true" android:paddingLeft="35dp"
      android:paddingRight="16dp" android:textSize="16dp" android:singleLine="true"
      android:ellipsize="end" />                                        and this in the code                  title.setText(formSummary.formTitle + Html.fromHtml("<SUP>SM</SUP>"));

Comment: Try this code: `title.setText(Html.fromHtml(formSummary.formTitle + "<SUP>SM</SUP>"));`